# TensorFlow: How to Import Weights from Sub-Graph of Computational Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have two models in TensorFlow, let's call them `A` and `B`.

Model `A`'s computation graph looks like

```
X -> Y -> P -> Z
```

Model `B`'s computation graph looks like

```
X' -> Y' -> P -> Q -> Z'
```

I have trained model `A` on a particular data set. I want to import the trained weights from node `P` of model `A` into node `P` of model `B` as well. How do I do this in TensorFlow?

I am using TensorFlow version 1.2.1 on Python 2.7